# Rewriting $e^{2xi} + e^{-2xi}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm trying to solve the differential equation $y^{''} + 2y^{'} + 5y = 0$

I get that the general solution is:
$$y = Ae^{-x + 2xi} + Be^{-x-2xi} $$ $$y = e^{-x}(Ae^{2xi} + Be^{-2xi}) $$ $$ y = e^{-x}(A\cos(2x) + Ai\sin(2x) + B\cos(-2x) + Bi\sin(-2x))$$

In the book the answer is written as:
$$y = e^{-x}(A\cos(2x) + B\sin(2x))$$

How can my answer be rewritten to equal the book's? Or did I do wrong somewhere?

Comment: Hint: $\sin(-2x)=-\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(-2x)=\cos(2x)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but I'm not sure how to go about it since there are constants involved.

Comment: You got $$y=e^{-x}\left((A+B)\cos(2x) + i(A-B)\sin(2x)\right)$$ So, letting $C=A+B$ and $D=A-B$, you've got $$y=e^{-x}\left(C\cos(2x)+D\sin(2x)\right)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $\sin(-2x)=-\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(-2x)=\cos(2x),$
your result is $$y=e^{-x}\left((A+B)\cos(2x) + i(A-B)\sin(2x)\right)$$

So, letting $C=A+B$ and $D=i(A-B)$, you've got $$y=e^{-x}\left(C\cos(2x)+D\sin(2x)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! Why does i disappear though?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been $D=i(A-B)$. I've fixed.

Comment: @lawls , $i$ though is imaginary is also a constant , and it  doesn't matter if you combine it with two other constant $A-B$ to have another constant $D$ , in the end it's still a constant.

Comment: @Mann OP was just commenting on my erroneous first pass, where I had written $D=A-B$ and left out the $i$ in the next line.

Answer (score 2):

if the solution to the charachteristic equation is $a + ib$, then the solution of the differential equation are in the form

$$e^{ax}(\cos(bx) + i\sin(bx))$$

Then of course [$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity), so the two formulas are equivalent.

---

You are writing the solution like $$Ae^{(a+ib)x} + Be^{(a-ib)x}$$

But This is equivalent to  $$e^{ax}(Ae^{ibx} + Be^{-ibx}) = e^{ax}(A\cos bx + iA\sin bx + B\cos bx - iB\sin bx) = e^{ax}((A+B)\cos x + i(A-B)\sin bx)$$

Thanks to the fact that $\cos x$ is even and $\sin x$ is odd. 
Now the two constants $A+B$ and $A-B$ are independent, therefore you may just call $A+B = C$ and $A-B=D$ and you get the same solution as written in the book

Comment: You aren't actually answering the question, just giving a general rule, a rule it would seem the OP is trying to understand with this question.

Comment: As @ThomasAndrews pointed out. How do you get to that?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right! edited :-) Let me know if it's okay!

Comment: @lawls it should be clear now :-)